# Taylor Polynomial with E

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Estimate $e^{0.1}$ to $6$ decimal places using a Taylor polynomial about $0$. Use error bounding to prove that your estimate is accurate to at least 6 decimal places.

I think I will have to use the formula for Error bounding in some way. However, I am not sure how to compute enough derivatives to form the entire polynomial, and I am also not sure how to make sure that the estimate is accurate to 6 places. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: It suffices to ensure there is a term smaller than $0.0000005$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Lagrange form of the remainder: for all positive integers $n$, 
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} + R_n(x)
$$
where $$R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1} $$
for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$ (here $f(x) = e^x$). Obviously, $f^{(n)}(x) = e^x$ for all $x$, which is strictly greater than one on $(0,\infty)$, so this error is maximized at $\xi=\frac1{10}$. So we have the inequality
$$
\frac{\left(e^{\frac1{10}}\right)}{(n+1)!}e^{\frac1{10}} < 0.0000005.
$$
Clearly the left-hand side is monotone decreasing in $n$, and the inequality is satisfied for $n=9$ but not for $n=8$. So take $n=9$, for an error of
$$
2.783427*10^{-7}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Math1000's answer, suppose that you want $k$ decimal places, you need to solve
$$\frac{\left(e^{\frac1{10}}\right)}{(n+1)!}e^{\frac1{10}} = 10^{-k}\implies (n+1)!=e^{\frac1{5}}10^k$$ For the time being, let $m=n+1$ and we need the inverse factorial of $m$.

Have a look at @rogjohn's answer in this post and notice that the approximation of
$$m!=a \implies m \sim \exp\left(1+W\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{a^2}{2 \pi }\right)}{2 e}\right) \right)-\frac 12$$ Applied to your case, this would give
$$n \sim \exp\left(1+W\left(\frac{10 k \log (10)+2-5 \log (2 \pi )}{10 e}\right)\right)-\frac 32$$ and you will use $\lceil n \rceil$.

Below is given a table for a few values of $k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k & n & \lceil n \rceil & \frac{\left(e^{\frac1{10}}\right)}{(\lceil n \rceil+1)!}e^{\frac1{10}}\\
1 & 2.52768 & 3 & 5.08918 \times 10^{-2}\\
 2 & 4.00593 & 5 & 1.69639 \times 10^{-3}\\
 3 & 5.27585 & 6 & 2.42342 \times 10^{-4}\\
 4 & 6.43054 & 7 & 3.02927 \times 10^{-5}\\
 5 & 7.50863 & 8 & 3.36586\times 10^{-6} \\
 6 & 8.53069 & 9 & 3.36586\times 10^{-7} \\
 7 & 9.5093 & 10  & 3.05987\times 10^{-8} \\
 8 & 10.4528 & 11 & 2.54989\times 10^{-9} \\
 9 & 11.3672 & 12  & 1.96146\times 10^{-10} \\
 10 & 12.2567 & 13 & 1.40106\times 10^{-11} \\
 11 & 13.1248 & 14 & 9.34027\times 10^{13} \\
 12 & 13.9741 & 14 & 9.34027\times 10^{13}
\end{array}
\right)$$